# Xcode won't sign app

Tags: iphone, codesign

I'm almost at my wit's end with this. I can't get xcode to recognize that it's supposed to sign the @#$% app! I (think) I have my cert and provisioning file setup correctly. I've selected the appropriate target, and am using the Device Based SDK. The project builds without errors, but when I look at the Build Log, after GenerateDSYMFile I expect to see ProcessingProductPackaging, which I don't see. Nor to I see the CodeSign task. Why isn't xcode even attempting to sign the app?

I'm using xcode 3.2.4. Any direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Ok.. breathing easy now :) ... it's com.craigagreen.myapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure; Xcode normally refuses to even *attempt* to build if it can't sign it. There are some options about post-compilation steps (under "Deployment"); some of them might relate to code-signing.

Failing that, some other options:

- Restart Xcode.
- Restart your computer.
- Reinstall Xcode.
- Start with a second, empty project which does sign. Remove things from the first project or add things to the second until either the first one signs or the second one doesn't, and then `diff {MyApp,MyApp2}.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`. (Annoyingly, the diff is full of GUIDs that will probably change...)

Comment: One thing that I thought was kind of odd was that I no longer had a choice of Acitve SDKs. It would only show 'Device' (and without the check beside it). So I just created a new project and added all of my files to it... and it worked! I have no idea why or how, but the project file was obviously mangled enough that it didn't want to sign for me. I guess the Active SDK issue should have drawn my attention to the project file sooner. Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like it's due to an un-set Base SDK, except that results in "Base SDK Missing" or so. I'm not sure. I'd try to track down the problem, but everyone's a little bit OCD...

Answer (score 0):

First, verify the project settings:

1. choose Project, Edit Project Settings
2. Make sure the configuration is Debug
3. Enter 'code sign' into the search box and verify that under 'Code Signing Identity' that you have a valid profile (like 'iPhone Developer')

Then, verify the target settings:

1. Expand Targets and double-click on your app name
2. Repeat the same steps

Then, try building again.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I went through all of that before posting.